# how to upload to sftp phpstorm (mac)

Tags: phpstorm

So i've gone to Preferences->Deployment->Add->SFTP. I specified all the of the information correctly and testing the connection worked fine. I can see all of the files on the sftp in the remote server browser. However, when I click on a local file and try `Upload To...` I can only see the old mounted server connection (migrating servers). How can I set up my SFTP connection so I can easily upload the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to mark the Remote Server as "Default", and you'll want to make sure you have the Project Dir to Remote Dir mappings set up correctly.

See: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/deployment.html

Comment: I simply needed to put a `/` in the deployment path field of mappings. thanks